# Laravel 9 tailwind.css with vite

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, vite

I have troubles using tailwind.css when install according to https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel

When trying to run `npm run dev`

Error: failed to load config from vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: Cannot find module 'node:path' is thrown.

**tailwind.config.js:**

> module.exports = {
> content: [
>  './resources/**/*.blade.php', 
>
>  './resources/**/*.js',
>
>  './resources/**/*.vue',
>  './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
> ],
> theme: {
>  extend: {},
> },
>  plugins: [],
> }

**vite.config.js:**

> import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
> import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
> export default defineConfig({
>  plugins: [
>   laravel({
> input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
>   refresh: true,
>  }),
>  ],
> });

**app.css:**

> @tailwind base;
> @tailwind components;
> @tailwind utilities;

Comment: i had the same issue and it was node version, upgrade to node 16

Comment: That did the trick, thank you =)

Comment: I am having trouble with laravel-livewire and vite.  Node is version 16.8.  are you using laravel-livewire by chance, with Sail / Docker?  when laravel-livewire sends data back to the front end, the browser goes blank.  My background retains the bg color, but the form itself and all its elements disappear.  Have you had or heard of this problem and its solution?